$S + b = \tilde{S} + \tilde{b}$ iff $S = \tilde{S}$ and $b - \tilde{b} \in S$ for any subspaces $S, \tilde{S}$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$
My question is on proving an elementary linear algebra fact that allows us to define the dimension of an affine subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$. First, some notation: If $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then $A + x := \{a + x: a \in A\}$. So far I have established the following result. 
Lemma. If $S$ is a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then $S + b = S$ iff $b \in S$. 
I am a little stuck on proving the following claim. 

Claim. Let $S$ and $\tilde{S}$ be vector subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $b, \tilde{b} \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $S + b = \tilde{S} + \tilde{b}$ iff $S = \tilde{S}$ and $b - \tilde{b} \in S$. 

Proof. The "$\impliedby$" is easy: if $S = \tilde{S}$ and $b - \tilde{b} \in S$, then $\tilde{S} = S = S + (b - \tilde{b})$ by the lemma, and hence $\tilde{S} + \tilde{b} = S + b$.  I am stuck on the "$\implies$" direction. So far I have only been able to show that $b - \tilde{b} \in S \iff S = \tilde{S}$. 
Q: How do we prove the "$\implies$" direction? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Certainly $b \in \tilde{S} + \tilde{b}$ so $b = x+\tilde{b}$ for some $x \in \tilde{S}$, giving $b-\tilde{b} \in \tilde{S}$.  The dual argument gives $b - \tilde{b} \in S$.  Can you handle the rest?

@Randall: Yes, thank you!

You should finish it out and answer your own question.

More generally, in a group $G$, let $H,K$ be two subgroups and $h,k$ two elements.
$$hH=kK\iff H=K\text{ and }h^{-1}k\in H.$$
Proof. $\impliedby$ is obvious. Conversely, assume $hH=kK$. Then, $x:=k^{-1}h\in k^{-1}hH=k^{-1}kK=K$ hence $K=x^{-1}K=h^{-1}kK=h^{-1}hH=H$.
